# I got the following error while trying to push my Django app to Heroku: TomlDecodeError("Invalid date or number")

Tags: python, heroku, pipenv, toml

When I `git push` my Django app to Heroku, I get the error below. How do I know what needs to be changed in my code from this error? I'm not sure which date information I misconfigured to raise this error. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be great! My Pipfile.lock settings does say python 3.6.4 when I am using python 3.6.3. Could that be the problem? Is there a way to update Python without having to reinstall all of my stuff?

```
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/toml.py", line 454, in _load_line
remote:            raise TomlDecodeError("Invalid date or number")
remote:        toml.TomlDecodeError: Invalid date or number
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

> Here is the full traceback error below:

```
:\Users\Jup\Drop>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 8.93 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you are using python-3.6.3, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.4).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with latest Pipenv…
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 272, in parsed_pipfile
remote:            return contoml.loads(contents)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/contoml/__init__.py", line 15, in loa
ds
remote:            elements = parse_tokens(tokens)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/prettytoml/parser/__init__.py", line
17, in parse_tokens
remote:            return _parse_token_stream(TokenStream(tokens))
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/prettytoml/parser/__init__.py", line
32, in _parse_token_stream
remote:            raise ParsingError('Failed to parse line {}'.format(pending.head.row))
remote:        prettytoml.parser.errors.ParsingError: Failed to parse line 15
remote:
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
remote:            sys.exit(cli())
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
remote:            return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
remote:            rv = self.invoke(ctx)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
remote:            return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
remote:            return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
remote:            return callback(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 1775, in install
remote:            pre = project.settings.get('allow_prereleases')
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 293, in settings
remote:            return self.parsed_pipfile.get('pipenv', {})
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 274, in parsed_pipfile
remote:            return toml.loads(contents)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/toml.py", line 373, in loads
remote:            multibackslash)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_913f5397888fc6f8943894f7ab01ea65/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/toml.py", line 454, in _load_line
remote:            raise TomlDecodeError("Invalid date or number")
remote:        toml.TomlDecodeError: Invalid date or number
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to shrouded-ocean-19461.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/shrouded-ocean-19461.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shrouded-ocean-19461.git'
```

The error may be in my `Pipfile`. Could an incorrect version number be the problem?

```
    [[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"


[packages]

amqp==2.2.2
anyjson==0.3.3
apache-libcloud==2.2.1
arrow==0.12.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
billiard==3.5.0.3
blessed==1.14.2
bs4==0.0.1
celery==4.1.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cx-Freeze==6.0b1
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==2.0
django-celery==3.2.2
django-celery-beat==1.1.0
django-celery-results==1.0.1
django-heroku==0.2.0
django-picklefield==1.0.0
django-q==0.8.1
django-redis-cache==1.7.1
enum-compat==0.0.2
eventlet==0.21.0
flake8==3.5.0
greenlet==0.4.12
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
kombu==4.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
mtgsdk==1.3.1
numpy==1.13.3
olefile==0.44
pandas==0.21.0
pew==1.1.1
Pillow==4.3.0
pipenv==9.0.0
psutil==5.3.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycurl==7.43.0.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.3
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
selenium==3.7.0
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
vine==1.1.4
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.12.2
whitenoise==3.3.1


[dev-packages]
```

Comment: The error is from `pipenv`; seems you have problems in `Pipfile`.

Comment: @phd I see! I'll look there. I updated code with my Pipfile info. Would an incorrect version number cause that problem? I know I have to delete I lot of unused requirements. In my pipfile.lock settings it say `python 3.6.4` in a few locations, but I have python 3.6.3. Could that be the issue?

Comment: The error message includes text `Failed to parse line 15`.

Comment: @phd I see. I actually found that my Pipfile.lock had incorrect formatting. I changed it from `Django==2.0` to `Django = "==2.0"` and that seems to have fixed that problem. Now the error that I'm getting is `remote:        Your Pipfile.lock (af8c37) is out of date. Expected: (3ca3d5)` Any idea how I'm supposed to update this?

Comment: Regenerate it with `pipenv lock`, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my Pipfile.lock settings. It has a different format when replacing requirements.text. I changed the formatting like so:

```
Django==2.0
```

> To

```
Django = "==2.0"
```

But that raised a different error like the following:

```
Your Pipfile.lock (af8c37) is out of date. Expected: (3ca3d5)
```

I'll have to figure out how to fix this now. Please let me know if you have any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, Changing all the packages in the Pipfile with the example from  `Django==2.0` to `Django = "==2.0"` worked for me.

Note: I did not have a Pipfile.lock